# Unable to fix popper placement in autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popper.js

I am using the `<Autocomplete />` component of Material-UI and I have a situation where I want my drop-down to always appear at the bottom. Therefore I did this:

```
PopperComponent={(props) => <Popper {...props} placement='bottom-start' />}
```

My drop-down still appear at the top sometimes.

Moreover, when i did the above, the width of my popper is no longer the width of my autocomplete.

I decided then that i want to change the zIndex of the popper so that the app bar won't cover it if the position of the popper switches to the top.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `placement` appears to be broken when used in Autocomplete's Popper (material-ui v. 4.11.4).

A hack that worked for me is as follows:

```
<Autocomplete
  // Force menu to open below, with the correct width
  PopperComponent={({ style, ...props }) => (
    <Popper
      {...props}
      style={{ ...style, height: 0 }} // width is passed in 'style' prop
    />
  )}
  // Set menu max height (optional)
  ListboxProps={{ style: { maxHeight: '30vh' } }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using MUI 5.4.4 and ran into a similar issue where the `Autocompelete`s `Popper` component was trying to flip to the top (and therefor disappearing) when there wasn't enough space on the bottom of the page. I fixed the issue by creating custom popper component with a `flip` modifier with the `fallbackPlacements` option set to an empty array and setting the `popperOptions` placement to bottom so that the `Popper` menu is always at the bottom regardless of if there is enough space or not.

The [popper docs](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/flip/#fallbackplacements) for the flip modifier explained it pretty well.

Custom popper:

```
const CustomerPopper = (props) => {
  const modifiers = [
    {
      name: 'flip',
      options: {
        fallbackPlacements: []
      },
    },
  ]

  return (
    <Popper
      {...props}
      modifiers={modifiers}
      popperOptions={{
        placement: 'bottom',
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Autocomplete:

```
<Autocomplete
  {...otherStuff}
  PopperComponent={(props) => <CustomerPopper {...props} />}
/>
```

Comment: This is happening for me too. Your solution works but do you know why does it disappear when it's trying to flip? Is that a bug? I'm using version @mui/material": "^5.11.8",

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for an answer. You can achieve this by using flip modifier

```
const CustomerPopper = (props: any) => <Popper
        {...props} 
        modifiers={{
            flip: {
                enabled: false,
            }
        }}
        popperOptions={{
         placement:'bottom',
        }}
    />;
```